# What do you call a person who add records to a log?

Tags: vocabulary

I have a log with records. How do you call a person who adds records to this log? a Logger maybe?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the field it can be specific,

I would avoid "logger", as it can mean "lumberjack", and when used in a business context usually refers to software that generates logs, not a person who creates them.

> Data entry clerk

Is common if you're talking about a person who professionally enters data.

As with any written record you can use,

> Author

or

> Recorder

My preference would be "recorder" given that it is a term used to describe a person who takes down records, which seems best for your situation.

Answer (score 0):

A word used in business is ***loggist***. Although I can't find it in any dictionaries, it can be found in job descriptions such as [this one](http://www.skills2share.co.uk/Loggist-Training.aspx):

> **Loggist Training**
>
> The Civil Contingencies Act (2004) establishes a clear set of roles and responsibilities for those involved in responding to and recovering from an emergency.
>
> Our training is for those people who have been given the role and responsibility for keeping records and logs during emergencies and crises.
>
> We help learners to gain the knowledge, understanding, skills and confidence required for **the loggist role** by using good quality teaching with structured group activities and exercises.