# What do you call a person who keeps hold on documents/paperwork?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning, word-request

I am working on my research assignment and it needs me to list down my group mate's jobs on the paper.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Please be more specific. As it is, you could be looking for any number of things. (As the various answers already indicate.)

Answer (score 1):

This task or role can be performed by people with a number of formal and informal titles, including **secretary, clerk, recorder and bookkeeper (for financial records).

As a member of a research team, I think **recorder** is closest - as answered in a similar question below.

[What do you call a person who add records to a log?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/117974/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-add-records-to-a-log)

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on exactly what the context of your question is. It is not clear.

The context may be that only you are responsible for recording or documenting what tasks each member of the team  performed. In which case, R. Sole's answer of "recorder" is excellent.

(In a legal or very formal context, "secretary" in the sense of the person officially responsible for recording and retaining important information is preferable, but that word seems too legalistic for academic work.)

The context, however, may be that you alone are responsible for describing the methods and results of a research project for which others have done the work on which the report is based. In that case, I prefer the word "reporter," which clarifies that you are responsible for the text, but are not responsible for what lies behind the text.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, "secretary" is the most common term [in a formal group](https://www.skillsyouneed.com/ips/meeting-secretary.html).

> The secretary’s role in any formal group is to be guardian of the process of meetings. They are usually the person who makes the arrangements for the meetings, ... and keeps formal records of the group’s process and decisions: the minutes of the meeting. This may include keeping records of correspondence.

In a less formal project, the person charged with maintaining the repository of documents might be called the "record keeper" or "document keeper", depending on the nature of the work.  However in things like software development, this is normally part of the duties of the "project manager" who also does things like schedule meetings, assign tasks, maintain progress reports, and communicate with the client.

In any case it's not clear why you would need to have a person for this role.  Why not put all the documents in an online repository (e.g. Google Docs) and have them jointly maintained by everyone in the group?  That way they are accessible to everyone, and can't be lost in the event of a single computer failure.